# Exexute promise and use result to do more async calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, callback

What I'm trying to do:

1. Call Jira api to search for issues. (queryAllIssues)
2. I parse the response and add the issue keys to an array.
   So far so good.

But 3.
I want to loop over all the issues in the array and do another api call: listTransitions.
I am not able to get this working.
Can anyone help me out?

What I would really like is:

- define a function which does the first API call.
- In a second function I would get the result from the first function (list of all issues) (can't get this to work)
- work in 3 function to further processing.

See code below

```
const queryAllIssues = "project = Bla AND resolutiondate >= startOfWeek(-1) AND status = Closed AND issuetype = Story ORDER BY resolved DESC"
const listWithIssues = [];

function fetchIssue(){

const promise = new Promise(resolve =>
            resolve(jira.searchJira(queryAllIssues)));
let result;

promise
    .then((response) => {
    result = JSON.stringify(response)
    let js = JSON.parse(result);
    const listOfIssues = js["issues"];

    Object.entries(listOfIssues).forEach((entry) => {
        //data is in second place of array so get [1]
        let parsedIssue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry[1]));
        console.log("Issue key :" + parsedIssue["key"]);
        listWithIssues.push(parsedIssue["key"]);
        //get fields
        });
    },)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("data  : " + listWithIssues.length);
        listWithIssues.forEach((issue) => {
        console.log(" search string  = : " +queryTransitions+issue);

        let transPromise = new Promise(resolve =>
            resolve(jira.listTransitions(issue)));

    transPromise
        .then((newresoonse) => {
        let result2 = JSON.stringify(newresoonse)
        let js = JSON.parse(result2);
    },)
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Which jira API are you using? Do you have a reference to the documentation of methods like `searchJira` and `listTransitions`? Do these methods return promises?

Comment: jira-client: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-client
API: https://jira-node.github.io/class/src/jira.js~JiraApi.html

Comment: I cannot test code, as I don't have JIRA, so I will not answer. But there are indeed lots of problems with your code which have simple solutions. I will however leave it for someone else who can work with this particular API to answer your question if they wish so.